# Json information parsing

Tags: c#, json

Im somewhat new to json and i managed to save/load my own json files fine without any issues so far.

But now i got a json file from a game which includes informations about weapons. I tought i could loop trough that json file and fetch the informations i would like to get out of it.

Here is the file:

```
{
"APIresult": "000",
"APImessage": "OK",
"Total_Count": 382,
"Count": 5,
"Weapons": {
    "Weapons": [{
        "id": 3234,
        "status": 1,
        "create_date": "2019-03-05 11:28:51.48",
        "update_date": "2019-03-06 14:20:05.427",
        "item_id": "2010192501",
        "item_code": "C1878",
        "image_server": "https://z8games.akamaized.net/cfna/weapon/",
        "image_url_1": "300_169/C1878.png",
        "image_url_2": "100_56/C1878.png",
        "image_url_3": "800_451/C1878.png",
        "database_name": "AK47 Steel Empire",
        "item_index": 0,
        "sale_status": "",
        "item_type": "W",
        "item_category1": "",
        "item_category2": "",
        "item_category3": 1,
        "display_name": "AK-47-Knife-Steampunk",
        "weapon_description": "<p>The AK-47, previously gas-operated, has been completely redesigned to run on steam.\u00a0Hand crafted by master weapon smiths, this latest version will surely be a deadly addition to any arsenal.</p>\r\n",
        "weapon_power": 98,
        "weapon_accuracy": 95,
        "weapon_continuity": 53,
        "weapon_recoil": 76,
        "weapon_weight": 49,
        "weapon_load_ammo": 35,
        "weapon_full_ammo": 105,
        "weapon_range": 0,
        "weapon_angle": 0,
        "add_bullet": 5,
        "special_tag": "vip",
        "featured_weapon": 1,
        "duration": "P",
        "location": "VIPS",
        "currency": "ZP",
        "collection": "",
        "wdn": "201903071878"
    }, {
        "id": 3137,
        "status": 1,
        "create_date": "2018-12-12 02:07:04.707",
        "update_date": "2019-03-06 14:20:47.667",
        "item_id": "2010187401",
        "item_code": "C1827",
        "image_server": "https://z8games.akamaized.net/cfna/weapon/",
        "image_url_1": "300_169/C1827.png",
        "image_url_2": "100_56/C1827.png",
        "image_url_3": "1280_720/C1827.png",
        "database_name": "QBZ95_ArmouredBeast",
        "item_index": 0,
        "sale_status": "",
        "item_type": "W",
        "item_category1": "",
        "item_category2": "",
        "item_category3": 1,
        "display_name": "QBZ-95-Armored Beast",
        "weapon_description": "<p>A unique, but powerful adaptation of the QBZ-95. This weapon has been modified and upgraded with the latest in bio-technological wafare.\u00a0 Unlock the weapon's full potential by equipping it with its IAS and Desert Eagle counterparts! Don't leave spawn without it!</p>\r\n",
        "weapon_power": 71,
        "weapon_accuracy": 95,
        "weapon_continuity": 65,
        "weapon_recoil": 62,
        "weapon_weight": 43,
        "weapon_load_ammo": 35,
        "weapon_full_ammo": 105,
        "weapon_range": 0,
        "weapon_angle": 0,
        "add_bullet": 5,
        "special_tag": "vip",
        "featured_weapon": 0,
        "duration": "P",
        "location": "VIPS",
        "currency": "ZP",
        "collection": "",
        "wdn": "201812121827"
    }, {
        "id": 3065,
        "status": 1,
        "create_date": "2018-09-14 16:57:11.397",
        "update_date": "2018-12-17 11:33:54.067",
        "item_id": "2010168701",
        "item_code": "C1640",
        "image_server": "https://z8games.akamaized.net/cfna/weapon/",
        "image_url_1": "300_169/C1640.png",
        "image_url_2": "100_56/C1640.png",
        "image_url_3": "800_451/C1640.png",
        "database_name": "M4A1-S G Spirit",
        "item_index": 0,
        "sale_status": "",
        "item_type": "W",
        "item_category1": "",
        "item_category2": "",
        "item_category3": 1,
        "display_name": "M4A1-S-Guan Yu",
        "weapon_description": "<p>Inspired by a Chinese hero and his energetic spirit, a famous weapon maker combined the M4A1-S and the Glock 18C into one powerful package.</p>\r\n\r\n<p>In emergency situations, the attacked Glock 18C can be used to attack or the specially plated magazine can be thrown.</p>\r\n",
        "weapon_power": 67,
        "weapon_accuracy": 95,
        "weapon_continuity": 65,
        "weapon_recoil": 60,
        "weapon_weight": 42,
        "weapon_load_ammo": 36,
        "weapon_full_ammo": 108,
        "weapon_range": 0,
        "weapon_angle": 0,
        "add_bullet": 6,
        "special_tag": "vip",
        "featured_weapon": 0,
        "duration": "P",
        "location": "VIPS",
        "currency": "ZP",
        "collection": "",
        "wdn": "201809111640"
    }, {
        "id": 3013,
        "status": 1,
        "create_date": "2018-03-05 09:24:13.25",
        "update_date": "2018-09-14 17:01:10.81",
        "item_id": "2010163101",
        "item_code": "C1584",
        "image_server": "https://crossfire.akamaized.net/cfna/weapon/",
        "image_url_1": "300_169/C1584.png",
        "image_url_2": "100_56/C1584.png",
        "image_url_3": "800_451/C1584.png",
        "database_name": "AN94-Spaceship",
        "item_index": 0,
        "sale_status": "",
        "item_type": "W",
        "item_category1": "",
        "item_category2": "",
        "item_category3": 1,
        "display_name": "AN94-Transformer",
        "weapon_description": "<p>A rare and exotic variant of the AN94 Assault Rifle. This handcrafted masterpiece of weaponry has been designed from rare elements found in outer space, giving it the ability to transform into a deadly Turret to be able to fight supernatural enemies.</p>\r\n",
        "weapon_power": 78,
        "weapon_accuracy": 96,
        "weapon_continuity": 60,
        "weapon_recoil": 55,
        "weapon_weight": 44,
        "weapon_load_ammo": 35,
        "weapon_full_ammo": 105,
        "weapon_range": 0,
        "weapon_angle": 0,
        "add_bullet": 5,
        "special_tag": "vip",
        "featured_weapon": 0,
        "duration": "P",
        "location": "VIPS",
        "currency": "ZP",
        "collection": "",
        "wdn": "201803051584"
    }, {
        "id": 2966,
        "status": 1,
        "create_date": "2017-12-11 13:16:50.637",
        "update_date": "2018-02-16 08:28:07.43",
        "item_id": "2010157801",
        "item_code": "C1532",
        "image_server": "https://z8games.akamaized.net/cfna/weapon/",
        "image_url_1": "300_169/C1532.png",
        "image_url_2": "100_56/C1532.png",
        "image_url_3": "800_451/C1532.png",
        "database_name": "AK-12-Knife-Iron Spider",
        "item_index": 0,
        "sale_status": "",
        "item_type": "W",
        "item_category1": "",
        "item_category2": "",
        "item_category3": 1,
        "display_name": "AK12-Iron Beast",
        "weapon_description": "<p>A rare and exotic variant of the AK-12 Assault Rifle. Its unique materials enliven special senses in its owner.\u00a0 This handcrafted masterpiece of weaponry has been designed with the mysterious qualities of elemental Mercury.</p>\r\n",
        "weapon_power": 96,
        "weapon_accuracy": 97,
        "weapon_continuity": 59,
        "weapon_recoil": 52,
        "weapon_weight": 46,
        "weapon_load_ammo": 35,
        "weapon_full_ammo": 105,
        "weapon_range": 0,
        "weapon_angle": 0,
        "add_bullet": 5,
        "special_tag": "vip",
        "featured_weapon": 0,
        "duration": "P",
        "location": "VIPS",
        "currency": "ZP",
        "collection": "",
        "wdn": "20171211"
    }]
}
}
```

Im loading it into my c# app over this way:

```
        dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText("info.json"));
        foreach (var item in dynJson)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(nameofeachweapon);
        }
```

I already understand that i cant just say item.weapon.display_name to get each name of the weapons since its not going to loop trough each weapon id, it just sees the whole Weapons block as one and wont loop tough each item as im used to.

Since i dont want to create another quick and dirty workaround i would love to know what the proper way is to archive my goal over the json way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` with generic type.

Then use `JsonProperty` attribute mark the name of `JSON` key because there

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(File.ReadAllText("info.json"));
```

Here is the model for JSON data.

```
public class Weapon
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public string create_date { get; set; }
    public string update_date { get; set; }
    public string item_id { get; set; }
    public string item_code { get; set; }
    public string image_server { get; set; }
    public string image_url_1 { get; set; }
    public string image_url_2 { get; set; }
    public string image_url_3 { get; set; }
    public string database_name { get; set; }
    public int item_index { get; set; }
    public string sale_status { get; set; }
    public string item_type { get; set; }
    public string item_category1 { get; set; }
    public string item_category2 { get; set; }
    public int item_category3 { get; set; }
    public string display_name { get; set; }
    public string weapon_description { get; set; }
    public int weapon_power { get; set; }
    public int weapon_accuracy { get; set; }
    public int weapon_continuity { get; set; }
    public int weapon_recoil { get; set; }
    public int weapon_weight { get; set; }
    public int weapon_load_ammo { get; set; }
    public int weapon_full_ammo { get; set; }
    public int weapon_range { get; set; }
    public int weapon_angle { get; set; }
    public int add_bullet { get; set; }
    public string special_tag { get; set; }
    public int featured_weapon { get; set; }
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string collection { get; set; }
    public string wdn { get; set; }
}

public class Weapons
{
    [JsonProperty("Weapons")]
    public List<Weapon> WeaponList { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string APIresult { get; set; }
    public string APImessage { get; set; }
    public int Total_Count { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Weapons")]
    public Weapons Weapon { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can try to use `foreach` print `display_name`

```
foreach (var w in result.Weapon.WeaponList)
        Console.WriteLine(w.display_name);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fdF6dC)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i fixed the issue with the naming of the list named Weapons in the class Weapons since it wont work with both beeing named the same, but it wont get anything out of that json file, the foreach returns "null"

Comment: @Dennis I edit my answer and write the c# online you can try it.

Comment: That looks perfect! Thanks man. Did you use some kind of generator to get those classes generated that quickly?

Comment: sure there is a website can generated  class faster https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp

Comment: You just need to put your json data on the Left side penal.

Comment: Appreciated, exactly what i was looking for thanks!